# Best way to pass a string in C

Tags: c

I thought as

```
func(char* ary, size_t length)
```

or

```
func(char ary[], size_t length).
```

What do you think ?

Comment: Unless you intend to alter the string, the best way is `func(const char* ary, size_t length)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are absolutely equivalent.  An array decays into a pointer when passed to a function. You can use either one.

Comment: +1 , but why say , arrays decay into pointers , and not arrays promotes to pointers , is there a subtle point beyond the language ??

Comment: It decays because you lose information about the size and it becomes merely a pointer. `sizeof` operator can be applied to get the size of an *array*. But once you pass the array to a function sizeof will only give the size of the pointer (inside the function) and there's no way to get the array size. I believe it's generally called as *decaying* because an array becomes inferior (a pointer) than it was.

Answer (score 3):

if it's null terminated string , then just `func(char* str)` is enough, (otherwise you will not call it a string, call it a character array)